# For authentication of MongoDB: How to limit the number of login attempts? How to set session timeout?

Tags: security, authentication, mongodb

I am designing security policies for databases.

Is there any way to limit the number of login attempts to protect DB from brute-force attacks?
For example, user have to wait for 2 minutes after 3 falure of loging.

Is there any way to set a timeout for connnection sessions?
For example, kill connection session while there is no interaction for 20 minutes.

I hadn't found them by searching MongoDB documents and search engine. Please show me if anyone knows.

Comment: My recommendation would be to have a look at fail2ban (www.fail2ban.org) - it works great!

Comment: @digijay If MongoDB doesn't provide configurations for these, I have to create one on the outside.

Comment: And you'd have the benefit of being able to secure your other services, too (e.g. ssh or web apps that require a log-in).

Comment: @digijay Yes, you are right.

Comment: But I can't help you with the session timeout …